# C++ Find for building a single line calculator

Tags: c++

Lets say the input is
1 + or - or * or /
How do I recognize the different operators in a single line of code.
If the input is 2+3, how do I recognize 2+3 if there are multiple lines of input with 2*3, 2/3 and so forth. I can't use index numbers in case the numbers are really big
Basically, I am trying to create a single line calculator, how can I recognize these operators in cpp?

Comment: This will likely require more code than a single line/statement, unless you use a 3rd party numeric expression parser that you can execute in a single line/statement.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int a;
char op;
int b;
double sum;
cin >> a >> op >> b ;
if(op=='+'){
  sum=a+b;
}else if (op== '-'){
  sum=a-b;
}else if(op== '*'){
  sum=a*b;
}else if(op== '/'){
  double sum=a/b;
}else{
  cout << "Invalid";
}
cout << sum;
}

Comment: Thats what i used and it worked.

Comment: OK, so, you actually meant a "single line of *input*", not a "single line of *code*"?  You should have made your question clearer.  Also, since you already found the solution on your own, your comment should be moved to an answer, see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in StackOverflow's [help].

Comment: To get anywhere in the programming industry, you need to learn to (re)search first.  For example, search the internet for "c++ calculator example".  See also "Shunting yard c++".

Comment: Please **edit your post** with the code.  As you can see, code in comments is difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

You mention *single line of code*, which I will understand as a single line of input.  Reading a single line of text involves `std::string` and `std::getline`:

```
std::string line_of_code;
std::getline(std::cin, line_of_code);
```

The next step is to *parse* the *line of code*:

```
int number1;
int number2;
char op;
std::istringstream input_stream(line_of_code);
// Read in first number;
input_stream >> number1;
// Read in operator
input_stream >> op;
// Read in second number;
input_stream >> number2;

// Decide how to process the operator:
int answer;
switch (op)
{
  case '*': answer = number1 * number2; break;
  case '/': answer = number1 / number2; break;
  case '+': answer = number1 + number2; break;
  case '-': answer = number1 - number1; break;
}
std::cout << "Result: " << answer << "\n";
```

*Note:  The above code does not account for operator precedence, parenthesis nor multiple terms per line of code.*